# What acid will dissolve iron carbonate?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Issue: removing through dissolution a thin (2-4 mm) iron carbonate crust covering fossilized bone without damaging the bone.  Microblasting with conventional baking soda ineffective; removal of iron carbonate with mini-pneumatic air chisel also removes top layer of bone with the iron carbonate crust. Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: The mineral composition of the bone itself is required to make a good suggestion. Without it, my first bet would be potassium cyanide and my second be would be HF+H2O2

Comment: My first two bets are the same, only in a different order. Also, it would be not exactly HF, but a solution with a little H+ and a lot of F-. I suggest that you turn this into an answer, because both existing answers seem to be missing the point.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues arise immediately: 1) dissolving a variable thickness of iron carbonate (probably also of varying composition) and 2) not affecting the fossilized bone (which also probably has varying composition). A third issue might be that the iron carbonate seems to be either very tightly bonded to the bone, or perhaps even part of it by being part of the first substitution layer.

If the fossil is known to be mostly silica, acetic acid (vinegar) could work. Best method would be to scrub the fossil under the surface of the solution with frequent examination to see where additional scrubbing is appropriate, and where not.

If the fossil is largely calcium carbonate, recourse could be to oxidize the ferrous to ferric using a) calcium nitrite solution or b) hydrogen peroxide (H2O2). Calcium nitrite is a commercial corrosion inhibitor for rebar steel in concrete, and functions to oxidize ferrous to ferric at pH 11-12. The product at high pH is ferric oxide (hydrated). The aim in this process is to chemically attack the iron carbonate and turn it into something else that is not attached to the fossil. Scrubbing under the liquid surface (using rubber gloves!!) could turn the iron carbonate to a powdery product that is not attached to the fossil, at high enough pH to avoid dissolving calcium compounds. The chemical reaction is:
2 Fe++  +  2 NO2-  +  2 OH-  -->  Fe2O3  +  H2O  +  2 NO. 
The NO will oxidize in air to NO2 which forms nitric and nitrous acids in water, and is toxic, but so is the nitrite, so you have to be very careful not to breathe the vapors or leave the oxidizing solution on your skin.

Perhaps a safer method would be to use hydrogen peroxide. This reaction is well-known, but is usually done in acid; a pH of 5 should be safe enough for the fossil, even if it is carbonate-based. Doing the reaction in acid keeps the ferric iron soluble, but hydrogen peroxide is also reactive in alkaline solution and a high pH might be more suitable for carbonate substrates. The reaction is:
H2O2  + 2 H+  +  2 Fe++  -->  2 H2O  +  2 Fe+++. 
There is the added advantage that using excess peroxide causes foaming which could help remove particles from the fossil. Foaming causes mist which should not be breathed, and rubber gloves should be worn because H2O2 will eat your skin if you leave it on you for any significant period.